# Python separation by space

Tags: python, output

```
n = int(input("Give a number: "))
word = str(input("Give a word: "))
print(word.upper()*n)

n = 4
word = apple
```

output should be:

APPLE APPLE APPLE APPLE

now my problem is:
my output is APPLEAPPLEAPPLEAPPLE and I don't know how to put spaces between them.
I can't use split tho.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Muptiplying strings result an a exact repeat. Also works for lists, as you can see in the answers by others.

Answer (score 4):

Create a list of `word.upper()` and `join` its elements by separating them with a space:

```
lst = [word.upper()] * n
print(' '.join(lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(' '.join([word]*n))
```

Expalanation:
`[word]` - a list of single `word`

`[word]*n` - a list of `n` elements, each element of list is `word`

Python string method `join()` returns a string in which the string elements of sequence have been joined by `str` separator.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `print(word.upper()*n)` with `print((word.upper() + " ")*n)`

Comment: This code will result in trailing whitespace

Comment: which may or may not be what the OP actually wants.

Comment: `I don't know how to put spaces between them` - actually it is clear